# Do not take it for granted

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme

> Created by someone amazing,
>   With whom no one else can be compared.
>   sometimes you will be happy,
>   sometimes you will be scared.
>
> Sometimes it doesn't matter,
>   because you are simply not that concerned.
>   Sometimes it will stun you,
>   sometimes it will be just as absurd.
>
> You can tell your friends and family about it,
>   but, they might not believe you fully,
>   some of them might flat out reject you,
>   some of them might say,"Oh, really!!"
>
> You may stumble upon it,
>   be it at night or daylight so broad,
>   but, if someone catches you,
>   you will say,"Oh, sorry, my bad"
>
> Be careful though,
>   it is not one of the gods creation,
>   you will be mistaken, if you take it for granted,
>   it is just  ............

This riddle has been validated through Sandbox.

**Note** : The dots represent answer which will rhyme. And the answer *can* be, two or more words

Comment: If you are going to down-vote, do it in the sandbox! and specify the reason

Comment: Did you remove your post in the sandbox? I can't find it anymore (although I remember having upvoted this in the meta).

Comment: @IAmInPLS I did not delete it per say, I kept title and post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Imagination

Created by someone amazing,
With whom no one else can be compared.

> Amazing people imagine

sometimes you will be happy,
sometimes you will be scared.

> Imagination can be pleasing or scary

Sometimes it doesn't matter,
because you are simply not that concerned.
Sometimes it will stun you,
sometimes it will be just as absurd.

> Sometime one imagines sub-consciously and ignore. Sometimes it may lead to a work of art or science and may stun you and the world. Sometimes imagination is not clear.

You can tell your friends and family about it,
but, they might not believe you fully,

> You may describe your imagination to other

some of them might flat out reject you,
some of them might say,"Oh, really!!"

> Some may believe it and other may not

You may stumble upon it,
be it at night or daylight so broad,

> These may come in form of ideas in day and dream at night

but, if someone catches you,
you will say,"Oh, sorry, my bad"

> "The one where someone catches you might be >!if you daydream when someone is talking to you"
>  <sup>Thanks [naffarn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41408/do-not-take-it-for-granted/41412#comment122406_41412) for this one</sup>

Be careful though,
it is not one of the gods creation,

> Imagination is creation of your own. Whatever is created by god need not be imagined.

you will be mistaken, if you take it for granted,
it is just ............

> Imagination

Comment: I like this answer +1

Comment: The one where someone catches you might be

>!if you daydream when someone is talking to you

Comment: yes, you got it! I meant the answer to be 'a figment of your imagination'(it rhymes better. Changer it if you can, I accepted your answer anyways)

Comment: @smriti Thanks. You are right, `a figment of your imagination` makes even more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> a story

Created by someone amazing,
With whom no one else can be compared.

> a writer?

sometimes you will be happy,
sometimes you will be scared.

> Fluff and horror!

Sometimes it doesn't matter,
because you are simply not that concerned.

> Boring stories

Sometimes it will stun you,
sometimes it will be just as absurd.

> wierd/unlikely stories

You can tell your friends and family about it,
but, they might not believe you fully,
some of them might flat out reject you,
some of them might say,"Oh, really!!"

> tall tales

You may stumble upon it,
be it at night or daylight so broad,
but, if someone catches you,
you will say,"Oh, sorry, my bad"

> Not sure about this one...

Be careful though,
it is not one of the gods creation,
you will be mistaken, if you take it for granted,

> Stories can be made up.

Comment: nice answer, +1, but not the correct one. Also the answer rhymes with the creation.